# How to write own Converter in JSF

Tags: java, jsf

I have a question concerning JSF. If i want to write a own converter in JSF, it it necessary to implement the interface converter with the two abstract methods

```
getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value)
```

and

```
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
```

It is not clear for me, which methods will be called automatically in which JSF lifecyclephase?

Is it right, that the method "getAsObject" will be called, which a Request gets to the webserver and the method "getAsString" will be called, if the Response gets from the webserver to the client?

Greetz
Marwief

Answer (score 1):

Yes getAsObject is used to convert the input string to the object type of your choice when the request comes in. Then when a response is rendered and send out getAsString is used to convert the object to a string for presentation.

Comment: Thanks ! Are i interessted in my another question, which is quiettly similar to the current question?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031746/how-the-jsf-converter-fconvertdatetime-works

Comment: Anf if I created my own converter, these two methods will be called in every sceanrio or is there a way to prohibit that?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got the question right.

The client sends a request (data in textual form, e.g. amount=15). You need to convert the 
String to a number:

```
Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
  return Integer.valueOf(value);
}
```

Then it can validate the value (a range check or anything else defined) and apply it to the proper bean object.
When the code changes this value somehow you want to represent the object as a string to the client:

```
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
  return value.toString();
}
```

Comment: But value.toString() represent the value, which will be send to the client and its visible for my user, is this right?

Comment: Yes, you can return any String.