# How the JSF Converter f:convertDateTime works?

Tags: java, jsf

I have a question concerning the **JSF Converter**

```
f:convertDateTime
```

I i use this converter in this context (bean.date represent the Java class `java.util.Date`):

```
<h:inputText id="date" value="#{bean.date}" label="Enter Date" >
   <f:convertDateTime pattern="d-M-yyyy" />
</h:inputText>
```

Works this converter only to format xhtml page for the user in the response from the webserver?

Or will the entered value formatted with the pattern `d-M-yyyy`, if the request was send to the webserver and stored in the backing bean with the pattern format `d-M-yyyy`?

Is it possivle to insert some Date values from xhtml page into backing bean without using any kind of f:convertDateTime or is this absolutly necessary?

Greetz
Marwief

Comment: What are you trying to achieve or why isn't the `f:convertDateTime` good for you?

Comment: I mentioned in the describtion of my question, that i want to store a java.util.date in the backing bean and my question is, if a converter  is necessary or not?

Comment: Ok. The converter is necessary, because JSF needs to convert the String to a Date Object

Comment: But is it necessary to write JSF specific converter component directly in my xhtml page (please see the code example above)? Or can it leave out and the jsf frameworks works automatically with this converter in the background?

Comment: As @Eelke wrote, you have to put it there. Because JSF can't automatically resolve the date, e.g. 1.2. could be 1st February or 2nd of January. This is why you always have to define the pattern.

Comment: Ok Thanks, and i want to store int values in the backing bean for example, it is necessary too to set the JSF specific converter component directly in my xhtml page?

Comment: I think the `int` should work automatically. Consider please accepting @Eelke's answer as it answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converter is used for conversions both ways and it is needed because there are so many ways to write dates.

You don't have to use a converter if you use a date specific JSF component. Component libraries like Richfaces and Primefaces offer date components which won't require a converter and will directly validate user input.

Comment: But is it necessary to write JSF specific converter component directly in my xhtml page (please see the code example above)? Or can it leave out and the jsf frameworks works automatically with this converter in the background?